# Leaflet, How to draw a shape like paint(brush)

Tags: javascript, leaflet, paint

I try to use this plugin https://github.com/tcoupin/leaflet-paintpolygon for image annotation in multipoint circle-shape. but this plugin does not work properly due to a bug in libraries used in it. Is there any other solution to do this in leaflet or other JS libraries?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want a free-hand tool, you can create it without any plugin or library.
With the following code, you can start or stop a free-hand paint with a click.

```
let paintMode = false;
var myPolyline;

map.on('click', function() {
  paintMode = !paintMode;
  if (paintMode) {
    myPolyline = L.polyline([]).addTo(map);
  }
})

map.on('mousemove', function(e) {
  if (paintMode) {
    myPolyline.addLatLng(e.latlng);
  }
})
```

Here is a working jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/5drknva4/

Comment: Thanks but i want something like this https://tcoupin.github.io/leaflet-paintpolygon/ with size and erase options

Comment: You can still try and tweak the above code to do what you want. For example, the polyline is a typical layer so you can pass options for size, color etc. Giving an 'erase' capability wouldn't be hard, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can try 'Leaflet.draw' library (https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw), this plugin allows to create polygons and lines:

[Example in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgA6d.png)